# Can I send an array within Serializable object between ObjectOutputStream and ObjectIntputStream using socket

Tags: java

we have this object and need to send throughout socket :

```
static class Msg implements Serializable {
 int num;
 String name;
 boolean [] sign; 
 //modify 'Message' to 'Msg'....
 public Msg( int num, String name,boolean[] sign) {
   super();
   this.num=num;
   this.name=name;
   this.sign=sign; 
    Myarraycopy(this.sign,sign);
  }
 public boolean[] getsign() {
  return sign
 }
 // Some methods
}
```

however in other part of the code.

```
  Socket _socket;
```

one side

```
  ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(_socket.getOutputStream());
  Msg senMsg = new Msg(3,"Fine", new boolean[]{true,true,true})
      out.writeObject(senMsg);
```

................... in the other side

```
   ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(_socket.getInputStream());
        Msg recMsg = (Msg) in.readObject();
   boolean[] s = recMsg.getsign();
  System.out.println(s[0]+", "+ s[1]", "+s[2]);
```

why the output is: false, false, false.

how to retrieve the values of an array from ObjectInputStream;

Comment: I can only guess something weird is going on inside `Myarraycopy` method

Comment: Are you using a `boolean[]` or a `Boolean[]` as these are not the same type?

Comment: Is your class called `Msg` (in the class) or `Message` (in the constructor)?

Comment: Where is `Name` defined?

Comment: I assume you are using `writeObject` not `write`.  Can you show us the real code which compiles?

Comment: Please copy paste relevant portions of your ***real*** code. This code you have typed out doesn't compile. Particularly referencing `Boolean s = recMsg.getsign();` as an array when its not.

Comment: hi i am sorry for some silly mistakes i did in the code ,

Comment: it's works like this except the array part everything okay, Myarray is just normal to copy array.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you code doesn't look like it does in the example

This example works as expected (and compiles)

```
static class Msg implements Serializable {
    final int num;
    final String name;
    final boolean[] sign;

    Msg(int num, String name, boolean[] sign) {
        this.num = num;
        this.name = name;
        this.sign = sign;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Msg{" +
                "num=" + num +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", sign=" + Arrays.toString(sign) +
                '}';
    }

    // Some methods
}
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream boas = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(boas);
    oos.writeObject(new Msg(3, "Fine", new boolean[] { true, true, true }));
    oos.close();

    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(boas.toByteArray()));
    Msg msg = (Msg) ois.readObject();
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

prints

```
Msg{num=3, name='Fine', sign=[true, true, true]}
```

Comment: thanks a lot Peter,  yes my code is different a bit, actually i have changed after it doesn't work this way with me, but later decided to ask here
however, i have another question, if this works why it is must to use ByteArrayOutputStream?

regards.

Comment: How ByteArrayOutputStream() & ByteArrayIntputStream() work with Socket?

Comment: I use ByteArrayInput/OutputStream as I don't have a socket in this example.  If you have a socket, use the Input/OutputStream provided by the socket.

Comment: yes Peter we already have that. i mean the code already have getIn/Out-putStream

Answer (score 0):

Whatever 'Myarraycopy()' does, you may as well remove it, as you are calling it with two identical values. It therefore cannot possibly do anything useful. Copying an array to itself isn't useful, and clearly it is doing that incorrectly.

Comment: Myarray is not the problem. i may remove it or not nothing change.

Comment: Have you test that. the array only arrive with default values other values okay.